# Arquillian: Maven resolver result

Tags: maven, jboss-arquillian, resolver

The result of the call to

```
Maven.resolver().resolve("groupId:artifactId:version").
  withoutTransitivity().asSingleFile();
```

e.g.

`Maven.resolver().resolve("myProjectGroupId:myProject:1.1")
      .withoutTransitivity().asSingleFile();`

results sometimes in the correct jar file with the name

`artifactId-version.jar` e.g. `myProject-1.1.jar`,

but sometimes I get a file

`artifactId-unknownNumericalId.jar` e.g. `myProject-6244235517268120190.jar`

that doesn't exist in the maven repository. I couldn't find any hint under which circumstances I get the right file or I get the file with the unknown id.

Could someone help me here?

Comment: Maybe the actual code in question here might help.

Comment: I don't think it would help. There is a lot of code around, but before this call (the line is exact the same except the string), everything is fine, and after the call, the wrong file is searched in the repository. The correct file exists in the maven repository.    I hoped to find a hint in the arquillian api documentation, but there was nothing about it.

Comment: Do you have anything odd in your settings.xml file, or should the resolver be using it?

Comment: I don't have a settings.xml file. Is it for arquillian configuration? Weird is, that the call is used for several jar-files. For most of them, it works fine. Only for two files there occurs sometimes the problem described above.

Comment: The settings file is for maven, but that doesn't seem to be your issue. If it works with the others, what is different?